# Unable to add margins to .col-*-4 class without pushing the third float to the next line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, margin

I have been building a webpage for a class and we are using Bootstrap 4.
Thing is, every time I add a margin to one of my elements with the .col-*-4 class it pushes down my third element and I have no idea how to fix this.

I have tried using flexbox, but that just completely messes up the layout of my section. I have tried using absolute positioning but it is just a complete hassle and I have no idea how to fix this. I don't know if I have the wrong keywords because I can't find anyone who has had this exact problem.

I have already tried to use the flexbox portion of bootstrap, but it completely screws up the layout that I intend to have, and I have tried using absolute positioning but it's a hassle to deal with and I know that there is a simpler way. I just can't figure it out.

```css
/*Main Content*/

#menuTitle {
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

#chickenHeading,
#beefHeading,
#sushiHeading {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

#chicken,
#beef,
#sushi {
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#chickenBacktoTop,
#beefBacktoTop,
#sushiBacktoTop {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
}

p {
  color: #A9A9;
}


/*Extra Large, Large, and Medium Devices*/

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #chicken,
  #beef,
  #sushi {
    margin: 15px;
  }
}


/*Extra Small and Small Devices*/

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #chicken,
  #beef,
  #sushi {
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 650px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!--Main Content-->
<div class='container-fluid mx-auto'>
  <div id='menuTitle' class='text-center'>Our Menu</div>
  <div class='row d-flex mx-auto'>


    <!--Chicken Section-->
    <section id='chicken' class='bg-dark col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4'>
      <h3 id='chickenHeading' class='d-flex mx-auto justify-content-center'>Chicken</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus congue lacus in luctus eleifend. Curabitur varius dictum lorem vel posuere. Curabitur blandit congue ante, eu dictum nisl rhoncus sit amet. Aenean cursus lorem at turpis consectetur faucibus.
        Sed ultrices vehicula odio, eu laoreet neque suscipit quis. Aliquam sit amet lectus aliquam, suscipit massa id, pharetra ex. Nulla nisi nunc, posuere eget dignissim eget, malesuada sollicitudin libero. Quisque scelerisque porttitor ultricies.
        Sed eget ex sed ante euismod malesuada eget fringilla arcu. Aenean egestas tincidunt gravida. Praesent non mattis nibh. Cras aliquet efficitur ex, non imperdiet felis feugiat ac. Aenean sagittis justo sit amet enim congue, nec finibus velit vestibulum.
        Cras eros ante, tincidunt facilisis euismod sit amet, interdum ac diam. Suspendisse facilisis hendrerit sapien non ornare. Nullam nec magna nunc. Aliquam nisi magna, vehicula eu tellus eget, aliquam dignissim erat. Ut ut ullamcorper nisi. Etiam
        iaculis fringilla lectus id pulvinar. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris eu tincidunt risus. Sed eu bibendum leo, vitae convallis elit. Donec feugiat tellus a velit suscipit condimentum.
        Sed ut augue sagittis, facilisis mauris at, fermentum turpis. Duis dictum libero id dolor porttitor porttitor. Quisque tempor orci eu purus mollis, id semper tortor fringilla. Aliquam auctor pretium turpis at sodales. Morbi dictum neque arcu,
        nec fringilla velit porttitor ac. Cras tristique vestibulum dolor, id cursus tortor ullamcorper sit amet. Nullam varius imperdiet risus vel volutpat. Aenean dapibus, urna sed lacinia suscipit, enim ligula bibendum orci, non mattis nulla nunc quis
        dolor. Nunc neque ante, tristique vulputate mi et, finibus commodo urna. Integer faucibus in nisi consequat auctor. Aliquam quis odio eget lorem tempus pellentesque. Nam scelerisque viverra neque et ullamcorper. In ipsum nisl, sagittis ut est
        quis, viverra venenatis tortor.
      </p>
      <a id='chickenBacktoTop' class='btn btn-primary d-block d-md-none' href='#header-nav'>Back to Top</a>
    </section>

    <!--Beef Section-->
    <section id='beef' class='bg-dark col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4'>
      <h3 id='beefHeading' class='d-flex mx-auto justify-content-center'>Beef</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus congue lacus in luctus eleifend. Curabitur varius dictum lorem vel posuere. Curabitur blandit congue ante, eu dictum nisl rhoncus sit amet. Aenean cursus lorem at turpis consectetur faucibus.
        Sed ultrices vehicula odio, eu laoreet neque suscipit quis. Aliquam sit amet lectus aliquam, suscipit massa id, pharetra ex. Nulla nisi nunc, posuere eget dignissim eget, malesuada sollicitudin libero. Quisque scelerisque porttitor ultricies.
        Sed eget ex sed ante euismod malesuada eget fringilla arcu. Aenean egestas tincidunt gravida. Praesent non mattis nibh. Cras aliquet efficitur ex, non imperdiet felis feugiat ac. Aenean sagittis justo sit amet enim congue, nec finibus velit vestibulum.
        Cras eros ante, tincidunt facilisis euismod sit amet, interdum ac diam. Suspendisse facilisis hendrerit sapien non ornare. Nullam nec magna nunc. Aliquam nisi magna, vehicula eu tellus eget, aliquam dignissim erat. Ut ut ullamcorper nisi. Etiam
        iaculis fringilla lectus id pulvinar. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris eu tincidunt risus. Sed eu bibendum leo, vitae convallis elit. Donec feugiat tellus a velit suscipit condimentum.
        Sed ut augue sagittis, facilisis mauris at, fermentum turpis. Duis dictum libero id dolor porttitor porttitor. Quisque tempor orci eu purus mollis, id semper tortor fringilla. Aliquam auctor pretium turpis at sodales. Morbi dictum neque arcu,
        nec fringilla velit porttitor ac. Cras tristique vestibulum dolor, id cursus tortor ullamcorper sit amet. Nullam varius imperdiet risus vel volutpat. Aenean dapibus, urna sed lacinia suscipit, enim ligula bibendum orci, non mattis nulla nunc quis
        dolor. Nunc neque ante, tristique vulputate mi et, finibus commodo urna. Integer faucibus in nisi consequat auctor. Aliquam quis odio eget lorem tempus pellentesque. Nam scelerisque viverra neque et ullamcorper. In ipsum nisl, sagittis ut est
        quis, viverra venenatis tortor.
      </p>
      <a id='beefBacktoTop' class='btn btn-primary d-block d-md-none' href='#header-nav'>Back to Top</a>
    </section>

    <!--Sushi Section-->
    <section id='sushi' class='bg-dark col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4'>
      <h3 id='sushiHeading' class='d-flex mx-auto justify-content-center'>Sushi</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus congue lacus in luctus eleifend. Curabitur varius dictum lorem vel posuere. Curabitur blandit congue ante, eu dictum nisl rhoncus sit amet. Aenean cursus lorem at turpis consectetur faucibus.
        Sed ultrices vehicula odio, eu laoreet neque suscipit quis. Aliquam sit amet lectus aliquam, suscipit massa id, pharetra ex. Nulla nisi nunc, posuere eget dignissim eget, malesuada sollicitudin libero. Quisque scelerisque porttitor ultricies.
        Sed eget ex sed ante euismod malesuada eget fringilla arcu. Aenean egestas tincidunt gravida. Praesent non mattis nibh. Cras aliquet efficitur ex, non imperdiet felis feugiat ac. Aenean sagittis justo sit amet enim congue, nec finibus velit vestibulum.
        Cras eros ante, tincidunt facilisis euismod sit amet, interdum ac diam. Suspendisse facilisis hendrerit sapien non ornare. Nullam nec magna nunc. Aliquam nisi magna, vehicula eu tellus eget, aliquam dignissim erat. Ut ut ullamcorper nisi. Etiam
        iaculis fringilla lectus id pulvinar. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris eu tincidunt risus. Sed eu bibendum leo, vitae convallis elit. Donec feugiat tellus a velit suscipit condimentum.
        Sed ut augue sagittis, facilisis mauris at, fermentum turpis. Duis dictum libero id dolor porttitor porttitor. Quisque tempor orci eu purus mollis, id semper tortor fringilla. Aliquam auctor pretium turpis at sodales. Morbi dictum neque arcu,
        nec fringilla velit porttitor ac. Cras tristique vestibulum dolor, id cursus tortor ullamcorper sit amet. Nullam varius imperdiet risus vel volutpat. Aenean dapibus, urna sed lacinia suscipit, enim ligula bibendum orci, non mattis nulla nunc quis
        dolor. Nunc neque ante, tristique vulputate mi et, finibus commodo urna. Integer faucibus in nisi consequat auctor. Aliquam quis odio eget lorem tempus pellentesque. Nam scelerisque viverra neque et ullamcorper. In ipsum nisl, sagittis ut est
        quis, viverra venenatis tortor.
      </p>
      <a id='sushiBacktoTop' class='btn btn-primary d-block' href='#header-nav'>Back to Top</a>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Margins increase column width, which causes them not to fit on the same line and to wrap.
However, Bootstrap columns have gutters (padding) by default.

> Each column has horizontal padding (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This way, all the content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side.
>   [Bootstrap 4.0 Layout Grid - How It Works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works)

I recommend wrapping the contents of each column in a containing `<div>` and styling that element as desired (e.g. padding, background color, etc).

For example:

```
<section class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4'>
  <div id='chicken' class='bg-dark'>
    ...
  </div>
</section>
```

Here's a demonstration:

```css
/*Main Content*/

#menuTitle {
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

.secContents {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.secHeading {
  padding: 10px;
}

.secBackTop {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
}

p {
  color: #A9A9;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--Main Content-->
<div class='container-fluid mx-auto'>
  <div id='menuTitle' class='text-center'>Our Menu</div>
  <div class='row d-flex mx-auto'>

    <!--Chicken Section-->
    <section class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4'>
      <div class='secContents bg-dark'>
        <h3 class='secHeading d-flex mx-auto justify-content-center'>Chicken</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus congue lacus in luctus eleifend. Curabitur varius dictum lorem vel posuere. Curabitur blandit congue ante, eu dictum nisl rhoncus sit amet. Aenean cursus lorem at turpis consectetur faucibus.
          Sed ultrices vehicula odio, eu laoreet neque suscipit quis. Aliquam sit amet lectus aliquam, suscipit massa id, pharetra ex. Nulla nisi nunc, posuere eget dignissim eget, malesuada sollicitudin libero. Quisque scelerisque porttitor ultricies.
          Sed eget ex sed ante euismod malesuada eget fringilla arcu. Aenean egestas tincidunt gravida. Praesent non mattis nibh. Cras aliquet efficitur ex, non imperdiet felis feugiat ac. Aenean sagittis justo sit amet enim congue, nec finibus velit
          vestibulum. Cras eros ante, tincidunt facilisis euismod sit amet, interdum ac diam. Suspendisse facilisis hendrerit sapien non ornare. Nullam nec magna nunc. Aliquam nisi magna, vehicula eu tellus eget, aliquam dignissim erat. Ut ut ullamcorper
          nisi. Etiam iaculis fringilla lectus id pulvinar. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris eu tincidunt risus. Sed eu bibendum leo, vitae convallis elit. Donec feugiat tellus a velit suscipit
          condimentum. Sed ut augue sagittis, facilisis mauris at, fermentum turpis. Duis dictum libero id dolor porttitor porttitor. Quisque tempor orci eu purus mollis, id semper tortor fringilla. Aliquam auctor pretium turpis at sodales. Morbi dictum
          neque arcu, nec fringilla velit porttitor ac. Cras tristique vestibulum dolor, id cursus tortor ullamcorper sit amet. Nullam varius imperdiet risus vel volutpat. Aenean dapibus, urna sed lacinia suscipit, enim ligula bibendum orci, non mattis
          nulla nunc quis dolor. Nunc neque ante, tristique vulputate mi et, finibus commodo urna. Integer faucibus in nisi consequat auctor. Aliquam quis odio eget lorem tempus pellentesque. Nam scelerisque viverra neque et ullamcorper. In ipsum nisl,
          sagittis ut est quis, viverra venenatis tortor.
        </p>
        <a class='secBackTop btn btn-primary d-block d-md-none' href='#header-nav'>Back to Top</a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!--Beef Section-->
    <section class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4'>
      <div class='secContents bg-dark'>
        <h3 class='secHeading d-flex mx-auto justify-content-center'>Beef</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus congue lacus in luctus eleifend. Curabitur varius dictum lorem vel posuere. Curabitur blandit congue ante, eu dictum nisl rhoncus sit amet. Aenean cursus lorem at turpis consectetur faucibus.
          Sed ultrices vehicula odio, eu laoreet neque suscipit quis. Aliquam sit amet lectus aliquam, suscipit massa id, pharetra ex. Nulla nisi nunc, posuere eget dignissim eget, malesuada sollicitudin libero. Quisque scelerisque porttitor ultricies.
          Sed eget ex sed ante euismod malesuada eget fringilla arcu. Aenean egestas tincidunt gravida. Praesent non mattis nibh. Cras aliquet efficitur ex, non imperdiet felis feugiat ac. Aenean sagittis justo sit amet enim congue, nec finibus velit
          vestibulum. Cras eros ante, tincidunt facilisis euismod sit amet, interdum ac diam. Suspendisse facilisis hendrerit sapien non ornare. Nullam nec magna nunc. Aliquam nisi magna, vehicula eu tellus eget, aliquam dignissim erat. Ut ut ullamcorper
          nisi. Etiam iaculis fringilla lectus id pulvinar. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris eu tincidunt risus. Sed eu bibendum leo, vitae convallis elit. Donec feugiat tellus a velit suscipit
          condimentum. Sed ut augue sagittis, facilisis mauris at, fermentum turpis. Duis dictum libero id dolor porttitor porttitor. Quisque tempor orci eu purus mollis, id semper tortor fringilla. Aliquam auctor pretium turpis at sodales. Morbi dictum
          neque arcu, nec fringilla velit porttitor ac. Cras tristique vestibulum dolor, id cursus tortor ullamcorper sit amet. Nullam varius imperdiet risus vel volutpat. Aenean dapibus, urna sed lacinia suscipit, enim ligula bibendum orci, non mattis
          nulla nunc quis dolor. Nunc neque ante, tristique vulputate mi et, finibus commodo urna. Integer faucibus in nisi consequat auctor. Aliquam quis odio eget lorem tempus pellentesque. Nam scelerisque viverra neque et ullamcorper. In ipsum nisl,
          sagittis ut est quis, viverra venenatis tortor.
        </p>
        <a class='secBackTop btn btn-primary d-block d-md-none' href='#header-nav'>Back to Top</a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!--Sushi Section-->
    <section class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4'>
      <div class='secContents bg-dark'>
        <h3 class='secHeading d-flex mx-auto justify-content-center'>Sushi</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus congue lacus in luctus eleifend. Curabitur varius dictum lorem vel posuere. Curabitur blandit congue ante, eu dictum nisl rhoncus sit amet. Aenean cursus lorem at turpis consectetur faucibus.
          Sed ultrices vehicula odio, eu laoreet neque suscipit quis. Aliquam sit amet lectus aliquam, suscipit massa id, pharetra ex. Nulla nisi nunc, posuere eget dignissim eget, malesuada sollicitudin libero. Quisque scelerisque porttitor ultricies.
          Sed eget ex sed ante euismod malesuada eget fringilla arcu. Aenean egestas tincidunt gravida. Praesent non mattis nibh. Cras aliquet efficitur ex, non imperdiet felis feugiat ac. Aenean sagittis justo sit amet enim congue, nec finibus velit
          vestibulum. Cras eros ante, tincidunt facilisis euismod sit amet, interdum ac diam. Suspendisse facilisis hendrerit sapien non ornare. Nullam nec magna nunc. Aliquam nisi magna, vehicula eu tellus eget, aliquam dignissim erat. Ut ut ullamcorper
          nisi. Etiam iaculis fringilla lectus id pulvinar. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris eu tincidunt risus. Sed eu bibendum leo, vitae convallis elit. Donec feugiat tellus a velit suscipit
          condimentum. Sed ut augue sagittis, facilisis mauris at, fermentum turpis. Duis dictum libero id dolor porttitor porttitor. Quisque tempor orci eu purus mollis, id semper tortor fringilla. Aliquam auctor pretium turpis at sodales. Morbi dictum
          neque arcu, nec fringilla velit porttitor ac. Cras tristique vestibulum dolor, id cursus tortor ullamcorper sit amet. Nullam varius imperdiet risus vel volutpat. Aenean dapibus, urna sed lacinia suscipit, enim ligula bibendum orci, non mattis
          nulla nunc quis dolor. Nunc neque ante, tristique vulputate mi et, finibus commodo urna. Integer faucibus in nisi consequat auctor. Aliquam quis odio eget lorem tempus pellentesque. Nam scelerisque viverra neque et ullamcorper. In ipsum nisl,
          sagittis ut est quis, viverra venenatis tortor.
        </p>
        <a class='secBackTop btn btn-primary d-block' href='#header-nav'>Back to Top</a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```